# How to Push a ViewController with a ModalView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, uikit

How can I push a UIViewController (**VC**) presenting a modal view (**MV**) to screen with a single left-to-right transition animation?

I have tried:

- Setting the modal transition style of MV, and then adding both controllers to the `viewControllers` of the navigation controller. This however results in MV just being a controller dismissed as any other controller in the stack.
- I have tried presenting MV from VC with no animation, then adding VC to the `viewControllers` and presenting the stack as above. This resulted in MV being instantly presented when the transition to VC starts, while VC itself animates to screen as expected. E.g. the MV doesn't follow VC when it slides in.
- I have tried presenting MV from VC with animation enabled, but that results in two transitions: first VC animates to screen, then VC slides up.

I'm out of ideas, yet I would like a native and clean solution: How to transition to VC with a single normal left-to-right push, when VC is entirely covered by MV?

Key point is that MV animates together with VC; MV would appear and behave like a full screen subview, but when dismissed it animates off screen like any other modal view controller.

Comment: Are you trying to "present()" a VC with a custom animation as opposed to "bottom to top" animation? or "push()" with navigation controller that usually does the "right to left" animation?

Comment: According to Apple docs there are two ways to display a VC: present or embed. I believe embedding will not allow me to use UIKit animations to dismiss the view; I would have to roll my own (not really a problem, just a solution I feel is less clean). So I need the view presented in such a way that it can be dismissed like any modal view, yet displayed and animated together with its presenting view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this issue. I think UIPresentationController can provide an important clue here.

I try to make the answer as simple as possible here. You may change parameters or even subclass UIPresentationController to achieve a full animation as you wish.

```
         import UIKit


        //Green
        class TransViewController: UIViewController {

            // MARK: - Navigation


            override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
                // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
               let dest = segue.destination
               let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modelViewController")
                if let myPresenter = dest.presentationController{
                    myPresenter.presentedView!.addSubview(nextVC!.view)
                    nextVC!.view.center = CGPoint.init(x: nextVC!.view.center.x + nextVC!.view.frame.width , y: nextVC!.view.center.y)
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                         nextVC!.view.center = self.view.center
                    }) { (success) in
                        dest.present(nextVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //Yellow  ; "modelViewController"

        class ModelViewController: UIViewController {
            @IBAction func click(_ sender : UIButton){
              self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, thanks. However, unless I have set it up wrong in IB, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm seeing two transitions; red to yellow. Also the navigation bar is initially shown and then hidden after ModelVC (yellow) is shown. Is this also what you see?

Comment: Yes. You can change the offset or subclass to get what you really want. My point is to use uipresentationcontroller is a quick way to achieve what you want.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll dive into that a bit deeper.